# PHP: Securing database connection credentials

Tags: php, database, security

Just to make sure everyone is on the same page these are the credentials I'm talking about...

```
$user = 'user';// not actual user, not root either
$pass = 'pass';// not actual password
$server = 'localhost';
$database = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass,true|false);
```

So I'm talking about the passwords used to *connect* to the database, not the passwords in the database (which for clarification I have hashed with salt and pepper).

I have not read anything that I think remotely suggests you can have 100% foolproof security since obviously the server needs to connect to the database and get the content for visitors 24/7; if I am mistaken I would love to hear how this would be possible.

So let's presume a hacker has root access (or if that does not imply access to the PHP code let's just say then have access to all the PHP source code) and they (in this circumstance) desire to access/modify/etc databases. If we can not prevent them should they have access to the PHP source then we want to slow them down as much as possible. I can keep each site/database connection password in separate files (can as in I'm a few weeks from finishing multi-domain support) for each site and not inside of public_html (obviously). I use serialize and unserialize to store certain variables to ensure certain level of fault tolerance for when the database becomes unavailable on shared hosting (preventing site A from looking and acting like site B and vice-versa) as the database can sometimes become unavailable numerous times a day (my database error logs are written to when the SQL service becomes available again and catches these "away" errors). One thought that has crossed my mind is determining a way to store the passwords in one hash and un-hashing them to be used to connect to the database by PHP though I'd like some opinions about this as well please.

If someone has a suggestion from the database perspective (e.g. having the ability to restrict users to SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, etc and not allowing DROP and TRUNCATE as examples) my primary concern is making sure I am SQL neutral as I plan to eventually migrate from MySQL to PostgreSQL (this may or may not be relevant though if it is better to mention it). I currently use phpMyAdmin and cPanel and phpMyAdmin shows the connected user is not the same as the site's database user names so in that regard I can still use certain commands (DROP and TRUNCATE as examples again) with that user and restrict the SITE user permissions unless I am mistaken for some reason?

Is there a way to configure the context of where the connection credentials are accepted? For clarification a hacker with access to the source code would not be accessing the site the same way legitimate users would.

Another idea that crossed my mind is system based encryption, is there a near-universal (as in on every or almost every LAMP web host setup) web-hosting technique where the system can read/write the file through Apache that would introduce a new layer that a hacker would have to determine a way to circumvent?

I am using different passwords for each user of course.

I currently am on shared hosting though hopefully my setup will scale upwards to dedicated hosting eventually.

So what are the thoughts on my security concepts and what other concepts could I try out to make my database connection credentials more secure?

Clarification: I am looking for ideas that I can pursue. If there is disagreement with any of the suggestions please ask for clarification and explain your concern in place of debating a given approach as I may or may not have even considered let alone begun to pursue a given concept. Thanks!

Comment: this is not a constructive question, not fit for SO, please post a specific question, this will just lead to debate and discussion.

Comment: I fail to see how increasing the security of storing database credentials is not constructive. I'm not looking for debate though for ideas, I'll add that clarification to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is little to be gained from trying to slow down an intruder that already has root access to your system. Even if you manage to hide the credentials well enough to discourage them, they already have access to your system and can wreak havoc in a million ways including modifying the code to do whatever they wish.

Your best bet is to focus on preventing the baddies from ever penetrating your outer defenses, worry about the rest only after you've made sure you did everything you can to keep them at the gates.

Having said that, restricting database user accounts to only a certain subset of privileges is definitely not a bad thing to do if your architecture allows it.

Comment: I'll definitely adjust the privileges accordingly, wanted to hear it was a good idea from someone else first. Keep in mind I'm a web developer, I don't actually maintain the server.

Answer (score 3):

As code_burgar says, once your box gives root, it's too late.  That being said, I have had to implement additional security mesures on a project I was involved with a while back. The solution to store config files in an encrypted partition so that people with direct access to the machine can't pull the passwords off by connecting the drive to another PC. Of course this was in addition to file system permissions so people can't read the file from inside the OS itself.

Another detail worth bringing up, if you are ***really*** paranoid on security:

```
$user = 'user';// not actual user, not root either
$pass = 'pass';// not actual password
$server = 'localhost';
$database = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass,true|false);

unset($user, $pass, $server);  // Flush from memory.
```

You can `unset` the critical variables after use, ensuring they cannot be var_dumped or retrieved from memory.

Good-luck, hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You want to approach security in layers. Yes, if an attacker has root access, you're in a very bad place - but that doesn't mean you shouldn't protect yourself against lower levels of penetration. Most of these recommendations may be hard to do on shared hosting...

Assuming you're using a decent hosting provider, and recent versions of LAMP, the effort required to gain root access is substantial - unless you're a very lucrative target, it's not your biggest worry.

I'll assume you harden your server and infrastructure appropriately, and check they're configured correctly. You also need to switch off services you don't need - e.g. if you have an FTP server running, an attacker who can brute force a password doesn't need root to get in.

The first thing you should probably do is make sure that the application code has no vulnerabilities, and that you have a strong password policy. Most "hacks" are not the result of evil geniuses worrying away at your server for months until they have "root" - they are the result of silly mistakes (e.g. SQL injection), or weak password ("admin/admin" anyone?).

Next, you want to make sure that if your webserver is compromised - but not at "root" level - you can prevent the attacker from executing arbitrary SQL scripts. This means restricting the permissions of your web server to "read and execute" if at all possible so they can't upload new PHP files. It also means removing things like CPanel and phpMyAdmin - an attacker who can compromise your production server could compromise those apps, and steal passwords from you (run them on a different server if you need them).

It's definitely worth looking at the way your database permissions are set up - though this can be hard, and may not yield much additional security. At the very least, create a "web user" for each client, and grant that user only "insert, update and delete" on their own database.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for PHP(Linux) On the root create a directory say `db` and create a class and define all the database connection variables and access methods  in a class say `DBConnection.php` now your website is example.com you are storing your files in public_html directory create a php file under this directory  to connect and do all database operations and include `DBConnection.php` file using following statement

```
require('../db/DBConnection.php');
```

> this file cannot be accessed using 'www.example.com/db/DBConnection.php'

you can try this on your web site.