# Is it safe to keep mysql login name and password in php page

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

I'm new to this so please be gentle with me!

I have a PHP login page which connects to a MYSQL table (users) for validation

I need a username and password to initially access the table. **eg:**

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','masteruser','masteruserpassword,'users');
```

Is it safe to keep the username and password coded in the PHP file. I'm thinking it is because the PHP file will never be 'served' only executed.

Any tips please

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Securing database connection credentials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744568/php-securing-database-connection-credentials)

Answer (score 0):

PHP code is executed on server So no need to worry about this.

Only processed output from the php code is delivered to the client side in form of response in html and js.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally safe. But it will be much better, if you move it to config file

Comment: Uriil - thanks for that. If I move it to a config file, how do I ensure it never gets served? I presume the config file should have a php extention such as 'something.php'

Answer (score 0):

It's safe unless somebody reach your server.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, WordPress works this way. The database access credentials are in plain text in a file called `wp-config.php` in the installation's root directory.  WordPress is probably the most widely deployed MySQL based web app there is.  So you should be OK. WordPress seems to be working fine.  :-)

BUT: practice defense in depth. Create a special MySQL account for your web app, and restrict its privileges to the MySQL database (or databases) your web app needs. Don't put a MySQL administrative account in there.

Also, make sure that account is restricted so attempts to connect from machines other than your web host will fail.

Thirdly, try to use a MySQL server machine that's behind a firewall, and only accessible to other machines in the same data center.

Finally, keep routine backups.

If you're using a typical commercial shared hosting service they take care of most of this for you (maybe not the backups).

That way, if somebody does manage to crack your server and look at your password, they'll have a hard time making use of it, and if they do make use of it they won't be able to damage much. If they do damage your app, you'll be able to restore it from backup.

Comment: The `LocalSettings.php` file of MediaWiki is a similar example.